# javascript image onload function never called

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem while loading pictures in my javascript. Seems that the .onload function is never called and so the picture is not marked as loaded. Can you help?

Here is the code:

```
//image loader
var img = function (source){
    this.loaded = false;
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.onload = function () {
        this.loaded = true;
    };
    this.image.src = source;            
}

//default component definition
var component = function (x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.draw = function (offsetX, offsetY, img){
        if(img.loaded){         
            ctx.drawImage(img.image, 
            this.x + offsetX, 
            this.y + offsetY,
            img.image.width, img.image.height);         
        }       
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not use [jQuery .on() function](http://api.jquery.com/on/)?

Comment: @elementzero23 Because OP use vanilla javascript, not jQuery.

Comment: When/where/how is `img()` actually being called?

Comment: And where `compontent()` gets the `img`?

Comment: copy/paste JS in action

Comment: Guess: you're calling `img()` and pretty much immediately check whether `loaded` is `true`. Well, it won't be. It'll become `true` *sometime later*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Context #1**

```
this.image.onload = function () {
    this.loaded = true;
};
```

`this` referes to `[object HTMLImageElement]`, not to the `img` instance.

**Context #2**

Now, changing the code to:

```
this.image.onload = function () {
    this.loaded = true;
}.bind(this);
```

When you do `new img("http://serban.ghita.org/imgs/serban.jpg");`, `this` will refer to your `[object Object]`.

**Context #3**

Now, If you do `img("http://serban.ghita.org/imgs/serban.jpg");`, without `new`, `this` will refer to `[object Window]`.

**Solution**

It depends on the context of `this`.

- You change it with `bind`
- Or by declaring and external `var _this = this;` and then use `_this.loaded = true;` inside `onload`.

Code: https://jsbin.com/pasumab/edit?js,console